# Dynamic Proxy - Class Loader parameter when creating a new proxy instance

Tags: java, dynamic-proxy

I was wondering about when you call the `newProxyInstance` method when creating a dynamic proxy instance, what exactly is the `ClassLoader` argument for?

```
public static Object newProxyInstance(ClassLoader loader, Class<?>[] interfaces, InvocationHandler h) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

Many thanks!

P.S. I'm not sure how to use the code formatting tags correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5480003

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`newProxyInstance`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5b%5d,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29) defines its use to be equivalent to:

```
Proxy.getProxyClass(loader, interfaces).
    getConstructor(new Class[] { InvocationHandler.class }).
    newInstance(new Object[] { handler });
```

So, if you want a bit more detail about `loader`, you can look at the documentation for [`getProxyClass`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#getProxyClass%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class...%29). Basically, it just serves as the class loader that defines the generated proxy class.